# Starting a laptop with an external display as its primary and default display

Tags: windows-10, laptop, dell-inspiron, external-display, usb-c

I have a Windows 10 Dell Laptop with a malfunctioning (broken) display.

Is there any way to start / restart this laptop to have it use an external display as its primary default display? (e.g. USB-C)

Comment: Sure. Windows remembers the last video configuration you had. Plug in the external, Hold down the Windows key on the keyboard and press P  four times, then enter. This will enable "Second screen only" mode. Upon restart, if you haven't changed the configuration, these settings will remain

Comment: Thanks @Narzard but wouldn't that require the user to login first?